# How to count Hibernate Results without fetching them in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-2.0

Using a HQL query like this:

```
def accounts = Account.executeQuery("select distinct a.number from Account a") 
def accountSize = accounts.size()
```

This gives the accountSize but the problem is that the accounts will be fetched from Hibernate as well. Is there a command that allows to compute the size of the query result without fetching the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Account.count()` can give you the total count of rows of `Account` table.

Is that what you need?

If you need the HQL, then

```
def accountSize = Account.executeQuery("select count(distinct a.number) from Account a")
```